# Limit border width to create space for label without using background color for label

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[Current vs Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAqFM.png)

Currently this input field is created by giving the label a white background but its conflicting when the input field is on different colored backgrounds. Is there any way to have the border length to no longer need a background color.

https://codepen.io/ehaliseda/pen/OvJOVG?editors=1100

```
<div id="bg-red">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
     <label for="basic-url"><span>Email</span></label>
     <div class="md-form input-group form-sm ">
          <input placeholder="YourEmail@gmail.com" type="text" class="form-control bg-input" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>




.md-form.form-sm input {
    font-size: 1rem;
    }


    .md-form, .md-form .btn {
    margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
    margin-top: -17px;
    }

    .bg-input{
        background-color: white !important;
        border: 1px solid #bdbdbd !important;
        border-top-right-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-color: #4285f4;

    }

    input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]){
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #4285f4;
    }

    label{
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 2px;
        border-top-left-radius: 2px;
        z-index: 5;
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .md-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    opacity: 0;
    }

    .md-form input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
        opacity: 1;
        color: #bdbdbd;
    }

    .input-wrapper{
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }           

    input[type=text]{
        color: #626262;
    }

    input[type=text]:focus{
        color: #626262;
    }

#bg-red{
  background-color:red;
  padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: The current vs. desired image is different than your code in which the input has a white background in a red parent. Would you accept an solution in which the input has a transparent background?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there no way to stop the border of the input in one section.

If you want the input to be transparent against a colored background as show in the "Current vs Desired" image, you can have the label inherit the background color of the parent so that you *only* need to set the background color on the parent element...

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/P0OzvzqWiC

```
#bg-red{
  background-color:red;
  padding:20px;
}

.input-wrapper{
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    background-color: inherit;
}  

label{
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Its is a good solution! I did come across a small drawback. for a white background, you need to define a white background for this solution to work. is it possible to make white background color the default and then inherit any color if not white?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hacky workaround can be done using fieldset and legend.

Here is an example of how it looks:

https://jsfiddle.net/dalecarslaw/a5he0e5d/

```
<fieldset>
 <legend>Test</legend>
  <input type="text" placeholder="test">
</fieldset>
```